# Google Cloud Speech API - certificate verify failed in Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm using `SpeechRecognition` library.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

AUDIO_FILE = 'test_audio.wav'

with open("api-key.json") as f:
    GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS = f.read()

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)

print('Starting recognition...')
print(r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, credentials_json=GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS))
print('Completed')
```

When above code is run, an error occurs -

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed (_ssl.c:777)

The audio file and api-key files are in place.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to consume through proxy by directly editing the code of google speech client library in python. Specifically I edited the file at(it might be different in your case):

```
lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py
```

the class Request, method **call**, there is a line like:

```
response = self.session.request(method, url, data=body, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
```

I added the parameter verify=False to that call which will just ignore SSL certificate verifications. However that is not recommended since incurs in security issues. If you happen to have the certificates of the CA in the proxy you replace verify=False with cert="/local/address/to/ca/cert". Here is how I have it working:

```
 response = self.session.request(method, url, data=body, headers=headers, timeout=timeout,verify=False,**kwargs)
```